# Linux suddenly doesn't see my SSD

Tags: linux, ssd

I bought a new SSD a few months ago and it worked just fine. Suddenly, a few days ago, booting my system (Feren OS) takes forever and I get the error message

```
COMRESET failed (errno=-32)
```

And my SSD suddenly is no longer visible. Not with fdisk -l or any other command I tried. It used to be /dev/sda and that is no longer there. In my bios I still see the SSD though.

Do you have any idea what I can do? Is there a way to test is there's something wrong with my SSD? I already tried changing the cables, plugging them off and on, nothing changed.

Comment: One way to troubleshoot, in order to rule out or in any problem with the installed OS, is to boot any other Linux live session.